# How do I encode json object in Jquery Week Calendar Subject "parse JSON"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I use Week Calendar(https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki) in my project and language is ruby on rails but I have a problem with JSON object in my ruby code that return JSON data to weekcalendar.js file. 
How to do JSON encode of JSON object as a 2d array to JSON Array format?

See this code:

```
data : function(start_at,end_at,callback) { 
    $.post('/events', { 

     },
        function(result){ \\this function is a receive JSON object from ruby
        console.log(data); 
        getEventData(result)
     },'json');        
  }
```

and this is a JSON object by console.log(data):

```
[Object { created_at="2013-03-12T11:08:34Z",  end_at="2013-03-12T00:00:00Z",  event_description="wqe",more...}, Object { created_at="2013-03-12T11:08:41Z",  end_at="2013-03-12T00:00:00Z",  event_description="wqe",  more...}, Object { created_at="2013-03-12T11:10:26Z",  end_at="2013-03-13T00:00:00Z",  event_description="ewr",  more...}, Object { created_at="2013-03-12T11:15:39Z",  id=4,  updated_at="2013-03-12T11:15:39Z"}, Object { created_at="2013-03-12T11:16:45Z",  id=5,  updated_at="2013-03-12T11:16:45Z"}, Object { created_at="2013-03-12T11:17:21Z",  id=6,  updated_at="2013-03-12T11:17:21Z"}, Object { created_at="2013-03-13T05:13:39Z",  id=7,  updated_at="2013-03-13T05:13:39Z"}, Object { created_at="2013-03-14T08:11:50Z",  id=8, ...}]
```

Ok, I have JSON object, now function getEventData(data), I do jQuery.parseJSON(data); for encode JSON object but have no result.

Please see this:

```
function getEventData(data) {
      var eventData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(eventData);
      /*return {
         events:[
            {
               "id":eventData.id,
               "start": eventData.start,
               "end": eventData.end,
               "title": eventData.name,

            }
         ]
      };*/
```

result console.log(eventData); is a NULL.

Ok for now. How to do JSON encode of JSON object as a 2d array to JSON Array format for return to valid. Thank for every idea and sorry for my english skill.

Comment: if you think that my answer helped you i would appreciate it if you would accept it. If not let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: sorry i have no time to see this.Ok i will try you code is right But sometimes I have an idea to encode json in the controller or in the Model before it is sent a json to the Javascript.

Thank you for your help very much and I had to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have an error at your first function too. You call console.log(data) and then you call your function with a variable result.

I believe that you don't need to use jQuery.parseJSON on that because it's already an object. 
This is what the documentation says about parseJSON:

```
Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.
```

Your data is already a parsed json (Object) so you can use directly the json format without parsing it.

So your code would be:

```
data : function(start_at,end_at,callback) { 
  $.post('/events', { 

  },
    function(data){ \\this function is a receive JSON object from ruby
    console.log(data); 
    getEventData(data)
  },'json');        
}

function getEventData(data) {
  var events = new Array();
  $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    events.push({
           "id":value.id,
           "start": value.start,
           "end": value.end,
           "title": value.name,

        });
  });
  return events;
}
```

Comment: ok i try this but consol.log(data.id) in function getEventData(data) result is undefined
  But consol.log(data) in function getEventData result is a json object why is this?

Comment: Hmm you are right well it seems you have an array of objects that means you need an each. I'll edit the code to explain what i mean.

Comment: It should work right now with what i did it goes trough each object and takes the information and builds another object.